# Objective-c Length method that returns NSString

Tags: objective-c

I know that the "-length" method returns an int.  Is there any other method that works the same as the "-length" method but returns as an NSInteger or an NSString?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get a NSString from the NSUInteger that the length method retruns

```
stringresult = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u",[@"my string" length]];
```

with this, you can make your own method...

and here you can find more about [Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Comment: Technically that's not a cast.  Also, the format specifier is wrong.  The return type of -length is NSUInteger. This is a 32 or 64 bit unsigned quantity, but %i is for signed 32 bit integers.

Comment: yes i was just thinking about that it is not technically a cast sorry about that, and about the format specifier yes %i is for a signed int and NSUInteger uses unsigned int...